# Set ServiceBehaviorAttribute in WCF Client?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I need to set by code the parameter

`ServiceBehaviorAttribute`

```
private static BasicHttpBinding getBinding()//BasicHttpBinding getBinding()
{

    //WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
    //WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);

    binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;

    binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);

    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
    binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;


    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 64;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;

    return binding;
}


private static EndpointAddress getEndPoint()
{
    EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(HTTP_SERVER);
    return endPoint;
}


ConnectionToServer = new ConnectionToServer (getBinding(), new EndpointAddress(HTTP_SERVER));
```

Hot to insert in the `ConnectionToServer` this code ???

```
ServiceBehaviorAttribute sba = new ServiceBehaviorAttribute();
sba.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing is the endpoint configuration (i.e. the code you posted) and another completely different thing is the service behavior.

To set SBA.MaxItemsInObjectGraph you need to specify it in the execution behavior of the service contract which is done via a ServiceBehaviorAttribute in the WCF Service (not the client as your code implies).

i.e:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant,
    MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 34)]
public class WcfService : IDuplexService
{
    //service implementation goes here
}
```

Here's how you can set MaxItemsInObjectGraph on a ChannelFactory:

```
        DuplexChannelFactory<IService> cf = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService>(typeof(ServiceCallback), Server.ServerBinding(), ep);

        foreach (OperationDescription operation in cf.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
        {
            var dc = operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
            if (dc != null)
            {
                dc.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I just responded another one of your questions.